# Самостоятельная прорисовка узлов TreeView

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

Стоит задача обеспечить прорисовку текста узлов [`TreeView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.treeview(v=vs.110).aspx) своим кодом. Как следует из описания, для этого нужно выставить свойство `DrawMode` в `OwnerDrawText` и написать код для обработки события `DrawNode`. Однако, столкнулся с ситуацией, что решения в лоб не приводят к ожидаемому эффекту в должной мере, т.е. присутствуют некоторые сдвиги, артефакты или нарушение выравнивания текста.

Например, следующий код:

```
private void treeView1_DrawNode(object sender, DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.State & TreeNodeStates.Selected) != 0)
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, e.Node.Bounds);

        Font nodeFont = e.Node.NodeFont;
        if (nodeFont == null) nodeFont = ((TreeView)sender).Font;

        e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Node.Text, nodeFont, Brushes.White, e.Bounds);
    }
    else
    {
        e.DrawDefault = true;
    }
}
```

приводит к потере последнего символа текста при выделении в дочерних узлах и немного смещается текст влево:

[image: кривая прорисовка]

Из [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2053118/3240681) по сходную тему на enSO это можно объяснить необходимостью использовать `TextRenderer.DrawText()` вместо `Graphics.DrawString()`. Но в этом случае тоже наблюдается некоторый сдвиг текста влево. Код:

```
private void treeView1_DrawNode(object sender, DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.State & TreeNodeStates.Selected) != 0)
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, e.Node.Bounds);

        Font nodeFont = e.Node.NodeFont;
        if (nodeFont == null) nodeFont = ((TreeView)sender).Font;

        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.Node.Text, nodeFont, e.Node.Bounds, Color.White);
    }
    else
    {
        e.DrawDefault = true;
    }
}
```

дает следующий (почти подходящий) результат:

[image: почти правильно]

В общем, хочется понять, как всё же сделать правильно, а в идеале найти код, который обеспечивает прорисовку при `e.DrawDefault = true;`. В этом случае можно будет подправить его под свои нужды.

Comment: Cудя по испорченому квадрату и остаткам текста "ot" от слова Root вы нетуда вывели текст, вам нужно правильно вычислить отступ, выводить текст правее в ф-ции DrawText.

Comment: @nick_n_a, да, тут я налагал немного, подправил код в вопросе и вывод, но всё равно наблюдается сдвиг текста при выделении.

Comment: Возбмите  у e.Node.Bounds левую границу и подвиньте на пару пикселей)

Comment: @nick_n_a расширил на 1px. Вроде бы похоже на правду.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно сдвинуть прямоугольник прорисовки на 1 пиксель вверх, тогда текст будет выводиться на прежнем месте:

```
var rect = e.Bounds;
rect.Y--;
TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.Node.Text, nodeFont, rect, Color.White);
```

Но получить исходники того как работает `DrawMode = Normal` всё равно было бы неплохо.

Comment: Они работают просто, используется WinAPI из user32.dll DrawTextW, в Windows SDK в разделе TreeViews (раздел Common Controls) примерно такое же слабое описание методов. Библиотека <windows.h> А TextRenderer.DrawText просто мост между машиной с# (CLR) и WinAPI. А исходники ядра винды - может где-то уже и валяются.

Comment: @nick_n_a это понятно, но хотелось бы четкой последовательности вызовов, т.к. не ясно почему нужно всякие сдвиги однопиксельные делать, например. И почему-то выделение текста (классическим синим цветом) всё равно происходит, т.е. нужно явно затирать прямоугольник цветом фона сначала, а потом уже всё остальное делать.

Comment: Возможно на самом деле 1 пиксел с 4-х сторон занимает рамочка фокуса, которая рисуется DrawFocusRect(WinAPI) System.Windows.Forms.ControlPaint.DrawFocusRectangle.  У вас на рисунке как раз её не хватает.